# Replicate/Capture PivotTable with DAX EVALUATE

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

Is there any way to capture a DAX expression for a PivotTable?

I appreciate it comes through into DAX Studio as MDX, but I thought it was worth asking the question.

Does Power BI send DAX through instead of MDX?

Currently my `EVALUATE` and `SUMMARIZE` isn't replicating the PivotTable Total section...

**Update**

It's possible to import your PowerPivot model into PowerBI Desktop, capture the DAX in DAX Studio, and then execute it back against the PowerPivot model.

NB The DAX from PowerBI Report Level filters doesn't work against the Excel model, but slicers do. This may save someone 20 mins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mention already having DAX Studio, the below is a link explaining how to use DAX Studio to see the queries generated by PBIX file.

[Capture Power BI Dax Queries](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/capturing-power-bi-queries-using-dax-studio/)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That should help.